# tabela retornando null

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabela-html

quando tento pegar os valores que estão na tabela com o seguinte codigo:

```
document.getElementById("#tbl-info");
```

e é retornado null

---

html:

```
   <table  id = "tbl-info" class = "table table-bordered" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Xi</th>
            <th scope="col">fi</th>
            <th scope="col">Xi.fi</th>
            <th scope="col">(Xi - x̄)²fi</th>
            <th scope="col">fri</th>
            <th scope="col">Fi</th>
            <th scope="col">Fri</th>
            <th scope="col">Opção</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody> </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

JS:

```
function insertTable(i, Xi, fi, xifi, med, fri, Fi, Fri) { //

   var html = `
        <tr>
            <td>${Xi}</td>
            <td>${fi}</td>
            <td>${xifi}</td>
            <td>${med}</td>
            <td>${fri}</td>
            <td>${Fi}</td>
            <td>${Fri}</td>
            <td>
                x
            </td>
        </tr>
   `;
      $("#tbl-info").append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` não precisa de seletores como `#` ou `.`, o método procura elementos por id, você não precisa especificar que você está procurando um id com `#`.

Apenas use `document.getElementById("tbl-info");`